# previous tooltips remain on mouse move, and don't refresh!

Tags: c#, winforms

in C#.NET winodws forms i handled manual tooltip texts for different ListBox items like this:

```
private void lstFields_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            ListBox lstBox = (ListBox)sender;
            Point listBoxClientAreaPosition = lstBox.PointToClient(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);
            int idx = lstBox.IndexFromPoint(listBoxClientAreaPosition);
            if (idx == -1)
            {
                //toolTip1.SetToolTip(lstBox, null);
                toolTip1.Hide(lstBox);
                return;
            }
            Field fld = (Field)lstBox.Items[idx];
            string strTooltip = string.Format("Descriptor: {0} , ISO Field Number: {1} , Custom Value : {2}",fld.FieldDescriptor,fld.ISOFieldNumber,fld.CustomValue);
            if (toolTip1.GetToolTip(lstBox) == strTooltip)
            {
                return;
            }

            toolTip1.SetToolTip(lstBox, strTooltip);
        }
```

it works, but the previously shown tooltips don't hide when i move the mouse fast.
what should i do?

Comment: `toolTip1.Hide(lstBox);` on MouseOut ?

Comment: i fact when i move to another Listbox item , i don't leave the listbox, i'm still on it!

Comment: I put the following code line just before i set the tooltip text for my cotrol:

toolTip1.Hide(lstBox);
I cant focus what happens now, but it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: can I post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Check this article by me [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Dorababu742/5099/?ArticleID=7f8879d5-bb93-4971-ac65-5064c02f9db9)

Write another namely `Mouse_Leave` and hide all the tool tips that you don't want to show